# public key denied, but ssh key accepted

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm having trouble with pushing to git (or rather, git is having trouble with me) as when I `git push` I get an error:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I've looked at git's [help page](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey) for this, but all of the 'tests' that they suggest are passing, including checking to see that the correct key is being used by running `$ ssh -vT git@github.com`.  This seems to be where most people run aground based on the posts I've seen on SO, but it's working for me.  Here's the output in case I'm missing something.

```
OpenSSH_5.2p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.252.130] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/charliekim/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/charliekim/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/charliekim/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1+github5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1+github5 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.2
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/charliekim/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/charliekim/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
debug1: Remote: Forced command.
debug1: Remote: Port forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: X11 forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Agent forwarding disabled.
debug1: Remote: Pty allocation disabled.
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
Hi **! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
                                                                                            debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to github.com closed.
Transferred: sent 2496, received 3048 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 9462.3, received 11554.9
debug1: Exit status 1
```

Here is the remote URL in `.git/config`

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://github.com/[user]/[repo].git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: Can you show us the url for your remote in `.git/config`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your git config is missing the user, so git is trying to authenticate as you (`charliekim`), and not as `git`, which is the user Github expects.

Use the correct user, and you should be able to connect:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://git@github.com/[user]/[repo].git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Comment: @ThomasOrozco: As a general tip: copy the repo URL from the repo's page on Github. This will save you problems like this, and a few related ones (e.g. repo URLs on Github are currently case-sensitive) -- and if Github already provides you the full URL, why go to the trouble of typing it out manually ;)

Comment: @NevikRehnel Yes, that's correct (and if you create the repo, Github even gives you the actual CLI) : )

Comment: eep -- my previous comment was aimed at @dax heh. *NAMES ARE SO CONFUSING*